# How to get past the jQuery 2.1.1 Android app vulnerability?

Tags: jquery, security, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create an app using Apache Cordova.  I've written all the HTML, CSS and Javascript using jQuery 2.11 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.  Unfortunately, Google Play won't accept the uploaded app due to security vulnerabilities of jQuery 2.1.1.  As far as I can tell there are no newer jQuery versions that are compatible with the latest (and last) version of jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.  So...I'm wondering how to get past this.  Constructive suggestions are welcomed.  Thanks!

Comment: https://www.slant.co/options/851/alternatives/~jquery-mobile-alternatives

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Just wondering...if I choose a jQuery Mobile alternative, is it a matter of re-writing the code or do any of the alternatives have a search/replace kind of conversion?

Comment: I have no idea...

Comment: I've struggled with the same issues. If you go to another alternative, you will be faced with rewriting code. It is a struggle to find anything as easy as JQM, but since it is no longer being developed, you may be faced with that decision. The closest may be onsen-io. Framework7 is another option. There are many Framworks out there, but it is a hassle to change. Also, perhaps, just HTML, CSS, and javascript using Cordova would work for you. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input!  I made heavy use of the collapsible sets capability of JQM and I've had a difficult time find any other framework that handles it so easily.  Since JQM development has come to an end, I decided to learn React.js and I'm in the process of re-writing the code now.  Hopefully, React.js will be around a while and will prepare me to use React Native.

Comment: Here is an interesting answer about that issue: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124369/is-jquery-2-1-1-vulnerable-to-os-command-injection

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try using the uncompressed libraries and place them in a local "js" folder instead of using a source URL.